# Formula to calculate difference between two summarized fields in a Joined Report

Tags: reporting, joined-reports, custom-report-type

I have a Joined Report between two Report Types summarized by Account:

[image]

How can I include the difference `A-B` between summarized sums `A` and `B` on the joined report?

Answer (score 2):

One can use Cross Block Formulas to create formulas that work across blocks.

[image]

Choose Summary Fields to use summarized fields in Cross Block Formula.

[image]

Comment: But we cannot use Cross Block Formulas in Joined Report Type....Is there any other way to do this.
Regards,
Abhishek Sinha